# background audio working on iOS simulator but not device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, background

I'm writing an alarm clock application that works by playing looped silence in the background until it's time for the alarm to fire, at which point it plays the alarm sound on loop until the user opens the app. Here's my code from applicationWillResignActive:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"silence" ofType:@".wav"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[player setNumberOfLoops:-1];
alarmTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timerInterval target:self selector:@selector(playAlarm) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

here's the method triggered by the timer:

```
[player stop];
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarm" ofType:@".m4r"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[player setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

This works as intended when I test it on the simulator. On my iPhone, the timer's method does get called but audio doesn't play. I did add background audio to my plist file. The iPhone's case-sensitivity to the name of the audio file is not the problem and the iPhone's mute switch is off. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: apparently you can't initiate audio from the background. workaround is to call the method that plays audio from the main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.